(GraphQL) Are there any issues with using Apollo on the client and AWS Amplify on the backend?
We're currently using Apollo on both the client and the backend, but the backend is planning to transition to AWS AppSync.
AWS provides AWS Amplify, which works with GraphQL. As far as I understand, we can continue using Apollo on the client side and there's no need to switch to AWS Amplify. We can still use Apollo for GraphQL operations. However, I'm wondering if there are any limitations or potential issues with this approach, or if everything works smoothly?

"Should" just work as this is a pretty common configuration.

Hmmm in my experience using Apollo on the client and AWS Amplify on the backend is a feasible approach for web + mobile app building. Both tools offer functionalities that complement each other well. But there are downsides much like anything.
There is some complexity involved with combining the two which can lead to a higher learning curve. You also have vendor buy in and unexpected costs as you scale (cause AWS).
But totes doable.
